# Where are the attribute summaries in Join Attributes by Location in QGIS 3.2.0?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, spatial-join, qgis-3, user-interface

I have recently switched from QGIS 2.18.21 to QGIS 3.0, and as of today, to the shiny new QGIS 3.2.0.

I need to do some spatial joining so I was quite surprised to find out that in QGIS3, it seems, it is no longer a possibility to summarise attributes from the joined layer. The `take summaries of intersecting features` is just gone. As a result I am left with joined layers, where the input layer was a polygon shapefile and join layer point shapefile, but the point attribute data is not transferred to the joined layer, and joined layer attribute table is shown as empty.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try `Join attributes by location (Summary)` in the Processing Toolbox - Vector general.

Comment: Thank you Kazuhito for this answer. I was not aware of the functionality in the toolbox.

Comment: Thanks, glad if it worked for you. It is quite unfortunate this function is not currently accessible from Vector menu.

Comment: I was looking for the same tool. I'm glad I found it in the toolbox. But I wonder why it ist not possible to adjust the precision. Especially when I'm using the "within" argument it is necessary to set a precision. Does anyone know how to do this in QGIS 3.2.1?

Comment: Have you had any success with the `Join attributes by location (Summary)` tool? In my case it executes successfully but does not join anything. When using the `Join attributes by location` I get the expected result.

Comment: @jmbouffard did you have any luck with getting the tool to join? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Kazuhito It is better to add your comment as an answer. It will reduce the number of unanswered questions :)

Comment: Thanks @ahmadhanb Will do... ... I now see other comments. Will try to check these points and post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **Join attributes by location (Summary)** tool, which can be found in the Processing Toolbox `Vector general` group.

---

Some additional comments:

1. As of *QGIS 3.4.1*, this tool is only accessible from the Processing Toolbox. From the menu `Vector | Data Management Tools` only **Join attributes by location** tool can be activated.
2. As of *QGIS 3.4.1*, **Precision** option is not available (see the comment by [anikatietze](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/126748/anikatietze). To set the precision we need to use QGIS 2.18.
3. Sometimes we may see *"blank"* output using this tool (see comments by [jmbouffard](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/17814/jmbouffard) and [AWGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/97475/awgis) ). As far as I have tested, this occurs when we unuse both `Fields to summarise` and `Summaries to calculate` options. When we have many attribute fields, keeping these two options empty means that QGIS has to output tremendous number of combinations of statistics, and it fails (or, it takes a long time to show the attribute table). You can select one of options to help QGIS. Perhaps you do not need all these statistical outputs calculated at once.