# Difference between "Join attributes by location" and "Join attributes by location (summary)"

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, spatial-join

I'm using QGIS 3.4.4. I have a polygon layer and a points layer.

When I use `Join attributes by location` I get the espected results.

When I use `Join attributes by location (summary)` the task failed, there are no results.

What could be the cause for this inconsistency?

Comment: Have you checked this question: [Join by location (summary) returns null](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319328/join-by-location-summary-returns-null?rq=1)?

Comment: My main question is why there is a difference between the two joins?
Different join types did not solve the problem.
Using both layers with the same CRS did solve the problem.
This was not necesarry for Join attributes by location but was necessary for Join attributes by location (summary), strange.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there are two layers `"points"` and `"polygons"` with its corresponding attribute tables accordingly, see image below.

[image: example]

I will try to explain the how-to of both algorithms by means of Spatial SQL using a most-common `intersects` predicate.

### Join attributes by location

> This algorithm takes an input vector layer and creates a new vector
>   layer that is an extended version of the input one, with additional
>   attributes in its attribute table.
>
> The additional attributes and their values are taken from a second
>   vector layer. A spatial criteria is applied to select the values from
>   the second layer that are added to each feature from the first layer
>   in the resulting one.

`"Join attributes by location"` (one-to-many) can be interpreted as

```sql
SELECT p.*, poi.*
FROM "polygons" AS p
JOIN "points" AS poi ON st_intersects(p.geometry, poi.geometry)
```

So, in the result you will see polygons as many times as the intersection between point and polygon exists.

[image: result_1]

### Join attributes by location (summary)

> This algorithm takes an input vector layer and creates a new vector
>   layer that is an extended version of the input one, with additional
>   attributes in its attribute table.
>
> The additional attributes and their values are taken from a second
>   vector layer. A spatial criteria is applied to select the values from
>   the second layer that are added to each feature from the first layer
>   in the resulting one.
>
> The algorithm calculates a statistical summary for the values from
>   matching features in the second layer (e.g. maximum value, mean value,
>   etc).

`"Join attributes by location (summary)"` can be interpreted as

```sql
SELECT p.*, SUM(poi.Data)
FROM "polygons" AS p
JOIN "points" AS poi ON st_intersects(p.geometry, poi.geometry)
GROUP BY p.id
```

So, in the result you will see limited amount of polygons based on the intersection between points and polygons because [the SUM()-function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) was applied which groups values from points per polygon.

[image: result_2]

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Tutorials and Tips | Performing Spatial Joins (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html)
- [Where are the attribute summaries in Join Attributes by Location in QGIS 3.2.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287701/where-are-the-attribute-summaries-in-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis-3-2-0)
- [Understanding Join Attributes by Location in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis?rq=1)

Comment: Taras thank you, this is a very valuable explanation for me, but 
does it give an answer on my question, does it explain why both layers must have the same CRS for the summary join and not for the join?